# SPARK SQL evaluating string mathematical expressions from a column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe, which contains mathematical expressions in form of a string. Like

| Column A | Column B | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | x+y |
| 10 | 20 | x |

where x represents values from Column A and y from Column B. Using Spark SQL, I am trying to evaluate the expression to compute a Column D which would hold the value.

I used the a string replace expression which substitutes the values x and y with the actual values. But they end up being a string numeric expression.

**REPLACE(REPLACE(Formula, 'x', Column A), 'y', Column B)**.

| Column A | Column B | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 10+20 |
| 10 | 20 | 10 |

Expected Output

| Column A | Column B | Formula | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 10+20 | 30 |
| 10 | 20 | 10 | 10 |

Is there any way to do this without using UDFs? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me put it this way.  The word "one" and the number 1 hold different values.  If your data is a string, it is not in numerical datatype, and thus cat plus dog = ERROR.  Or in other words, CAST your string into an Integer and now it can handle math.

Comment: I got a citaiton for you here --> https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_casting.asp
Let me know if that helps and I will type up a real answer.  Although .. now that I think about it .. you are probably doing this on the SQL end .. but the concept is very similar, get the "numbers" into number format and then you can do equations with them.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I tried to cast the expression to INT. It returns null for the ones having a operation sign like +. It can handle the individual values alone.

Comment: Oh of course, INT can only be applied to the numbers themselves. But once they are numbers you can then be like number PLUS number and it will work mathematically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how difficult your expressions will get in future. But if they will get complex, then you should probably use python `eval` within an UDF to do evaluation. You can do the same thing in Native Scala UDF which don't have the penalty of Python UDF. Here's an example code using both. Don't be afraid to write custom scala udfs. They are very easy to write. And run as fast as native java code in JVM so they don't carry the penalty of python udfs which need to spawn a python process.

You can download the jar used in the following script from

https://github.com/dineshdharme/pyspark-native-udfs/tree/main/releases

You can take a look at the scala udf which was compiled to produce the above at this location.

https://github.com/dineshdharme/pyspark-native-udfs/tree/main/src/main/scala/com/help/udf

If you need to change the udf, you can clone the project and compile and run it using `sbt assmebly`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.jars", "file:/path/to/pyspark-native-udfs-assembly-0.1.1.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


data1 = [
    [3.0 ,9.2, "x+y"],
    [2.223, 1.343, "x+y*x-x/y"],
    [454.0, 12.34223, "x+y+2*y"],
]


def evaluate_exp(x, y , given_exp):
    new_exp = given_exp.replace("x", str(x))
    new_exp = new_exp.replace("y", str(y))
    return eval(new_exp)


evaluate_exp_udf = F.udf(evaluate_exp)

df1Columns = ["x", "y", "expression"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=df1Columns)

df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)


df_result = df1.withColumn("result_python", evaluate_exp_udf(F.col("x"), F.col("y"), F.col("expression")))
print("Result using PYTHON UDF")
df_result.show(n=100, truncate=False)


spark.udf.registerJavaFunction("evaluate_exp_udf", "com.help.udf.EvaluateExpression", DoubleType())

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("given_table")

df1_array = sqlContext.sql("select *, evaluate_exp_udf(x, y, expression) as result_scala from given_table")
print("Dataframe after applying SCALA NATIVE UDF")
df1_array.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Scala Code for UDF used above :

```
package com.help.udf

import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF3
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.util.control.Breaks._


class EvaluateExpression extends UDF3[Double, Double, String, Double] {

  override def call(x_value:Double, y_value:Double,  given_expression: String): Double = {

    var new_expression = given_expression.replaceAll("x", x_value.toString)
    new_expression = new_expression.replaceAll("y", y_value.toString)

    //println("Here's the new expression ", new_expression)

    val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
    val calc = toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse(new_expression))

    calc.toString.toDouble
  }
}
```

Output :

```
+-----+--------+----------+
|x    |y       |expression|
+-----+--------+----------+
|3.0  |9.2     |x+y       |
|2.223|1.343   |x+y*x-x/y |
|454.0|12.34223|x+y+2*y   |
+-----+--------+----------+

Result using PYTHON UDF
+-----+--------+----------+-----------------+
|x    |y       |expression|result_python    |
+-----+--------+----------+-----------------+
|3.0  |9.2     |x+y       |12.2             |
|2.223|1.343   |x+y*x-x/y |3.553239558451229|
|454.0|12.34223|x+y+2*y   |491.02669        |
+-----+--------+----------+-----------------+

Dataframe after applying SCALA NATIVE UDF
+-----+--------+----------+-----------------+
|x    |y       |expression|result_scala     |
+-----+--------+----------+-----------------+
|3.0  |9.2     |x+y       |12.2             |
|2.223|1.343   |x+y*x-x/y |3.553239558451229|
|454.0|12.34223|x+y+2*y   |491.02669        |
+-----+--------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid udfs cause I heard that if data volume is high it can be a bottleneck at times. But looking at it now, it seems there is no other option left other than to use eval function from python.

Comment: @Abhra You can use Native Scala UDF as I have shown in the code. They don't have the penalty of python udfs.